# Make an n-Juggler

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

I've been really interested with sequences that follow the property

\$a(n+1) = a(n - a(n))\$

recently, so here's another question about these sequences.  In particular we are concerned with sequences from the integers to the natural numbers.

A periodic sequence with the above property is an **n**-Juggler if and only if it contains exactly **n** distinct values.  For example the following sequence is a 2 juggler

```
... 2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,1 ...
```

because it only contains the numbers `1` and `2`.

An example of a three juggler would be

```
... 3,5,3,5,1,5,3,5,3,5,1,5,3,5,3,5,1,5,3,5,3,5,1,5,3,5,3,5,1,5,3,5,3,5,1,5 ...
```

because it juggles `1`, `3`, and `5`.

## Task

Given **n > 1** as input, output any **n**-Juggler.

You may output a sequence in a number of ways, you can

- output a function that indexes it.
- take an additional input of the index and output the value at that index.
- output a continuous subsection of the sequence that, with the given property *uniquely determines* the sequence.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so answers are scored in bytes with less bytes being better.

Comment: Are we allowed to print the sequence indefinitely?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Normally I would say yes, but since these sequences are infinite in both directions, I have to hesitantly say no.  (If you offer a compelling argument I could easily change my mind on this) If you can find a way to print in both directions that would be fine.

Comment: @WheatWizard How about a list into which values are indefinitely appended and prepended and after each addition the list is printed?

Comment: @Steadybox Sure that sounds fine.  Probably not the easiest way to do it though.

Comment: What does "with the given property uniquely determines the sequence" mean?

Comment: It seems the sequnces follow `a(n+1) = a(n-a(n))`, and not +

Comment: @Zgarb Sorry I made another mistake in the equation TFeld is right it should be minus.  I must be off it today or something...

Comment: @xnor It means that given the subsection you can use the property to derive all the other members of the sequence, for example if you know `2,2,1` is in the sequence you can find every other member.  Basically it means that it is a subsection that only exists in one sequence with the property.

Comment: I also think "uniquely determines the sequence" is a bit confusing, even after your explanation. How about outputting a subsection that can be repeated indefinitely both ways to construct the actual sequence? Like the repetend of a rational number.

Comment: @aditsu I choose the definition there very carefully,  it's a little more lenient in someways and stricter than others than the definition you suggest.  I would like to make it as clear as possible but that is the idea I want to use.

Comment: Except we don't really understand what it means... Btw, is my idea acceptable as an output choice? In fact.. the additional input thing might end up being easier.

Comment: @aditsu No your idea is not sufficient, for example `2,2` when repeated infinitely makes a valid sequence but it could also be a part of `... 2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,1 ...` thus it doesn't uniquely determine a sequence.

Comment: `2,2` uniquely determines the `…2,2,2,2…` sequence (1-juggler) and does NOT determine the `…2,2,1,2,2,1…` sequence (2-juggler).

Comment: @aditsu `2,2` does not uniquely determine any sequence, its part of both of the sequences.

Comment: Yes it does: repeat `2,2` once → `2,2,2,2`, repeat again → `2,2,2,2,2,2`, etc. There's absolutely no way to get a `1` from repeating `2,2`. The sequence you get is always unique.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67722/discussion-between-wheat-wizard-and-aditsu).

Comment: It looks like the property is no more.

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
t+*%E
```

Try the **[2](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=t%2B%2a%25E&input=3%0A0&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A0%0A%0A2%0A1%0A%0A2%0A2%0A%0A2%0A3%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)**, **[3](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=t%2B%2a%25E&input=3%0A0&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=3%0A0%0A%0A3%0A1%0A%0A3%0A2%0A%0A3%0A3%0A%0A3%0A4%0A%0A3%0A5%0A%0A3%0A6%0A%0A3%0A7&debug=0&input_size=3)**, **[4](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=t%2B%2a%25E&input=3%0A0&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=4%0A0%0A%0A4%0A1%0A%0A4%0A2%0A%0A4%0A3%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)** Jugglers.

Receives two numbers, **N** and **I**, separated by a newline and in this order. **I** is the index into the sequence.

This uses a quite simple formula: **N - 1 + N * (I % N)**. Its validity was [confirmed by the OP](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40787752#40787752).

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 9

How about this?

```
q~1$,=)*(
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~1%24%2C%3D)*(&input=3%200)

Input is `n i` where `n` is the main input and `i` is the index you want to get the value for.

**Explanation:**

```
q~    read and evaluate the input (n and i)
1$    copy n
,=    basically this is a modulo (i%n) that avoids a negative result for negative i
)*    increment, then multiply by n
(     decrement
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 20 bytes

```python
lambda n,i:i%n*n+n-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFPJ9MqUzVPK087T9fwf1p@kUKeQmaeQlFiXnqqhpGOuaYVlwJINBMhamqgaVVQlJlXopCmAdSuqcOlAOb@BwA)

Same principle as [Mr. Xcoder's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146397/38592)

Comment: Should _principal_ not rather read _principle_?

Comment: @JonathanFrech... yeah..

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 17 bytes

```hs
n!i=i`mod`n*n+n-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P08x0zYzITc/JSFPK087T9fwf25iZp6CrUJuYoGvQkFRZl6JQnR0noKiQqZCDRDb6CpEG@rpGRrExgL5eWC@kZ6eaWzsfwA)

Another answer using Mr. Xcoder's idea. I wouldn't be able to answer the question otherwise to be honest. :P

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
%›*‹
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIl4oC6KuKAuSIsIiIsIjNcbjAiXQ==)

Comment: without the -1 your function obeys \$a(n)=a(n-a(n))\$.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 15 bytes

```java
n->i->i%n*n+n-1
```

Boring port of [*@Mr.Xcoder*'s Pyth answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146397/52210).

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jU4xasNAEOz1isUQOEXREQdSSafS4MKVy5DicpbNyue9Q1oZjNHblRUc2EWKwMIMzMzOdPZqyxBb6g7n2Xk7DLCzSPcMYGDL6KAThx4ZvT6O5BgD6U0i9Za4PbX92/9MiTQNODAwU9mg3Au9UkHleq6kUy6OP15qU/s14AEuskjtuUc6fX2DzZd1AMfQKyQGMh8VUG3W7wJFkdSHjkYErM3nAk86wP42cHvRYWQd5Tkrp22M/qYoTwTzYgWrvEqRKfs76Eklz@KYsmn@BQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
Ɠ%×+’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///YZNXD07UfNcz8/9/gvwkA)

Port of Mr. Xcoder's approach. The index I is in STDIN, N is an argument.